# openssl commands for certificate

Tags: openssl

does this openssl command generate a self-signed certificate file? I know that a csf should be signed by CA to generate a certificate.

"openssl ca -config /etc/openssl.cnf \
        -extensions client_cert -batch -in users/$name.csr -out users/$name.crt 2> /dev/null"

Answer (score 0):

let me answer it myself:

the command: openssl ca, would signed the certificate request(name.csr) with the private CA's private key, that is, encrypt the signature field in the certificate with the CA's private key, the output is the name.crt